# Custom Field OrchardCMS

Tags: orchardcms

I have used following way to create custom dropdown field to insert it into my custom form. Now all I need is to configure this field from admin panel for filter purpose.Like from admin panel I will be able to write a filter in text box and that filter will go with ajax call as a parameter to retrieve filtered data from database.

I would highly appreciate your help in this regard.

MyModule/Fields/MyCustomField.cs:

```
public class MyCustomField : ContentField {
    public string SelectedValue {
        get { return Storage.Get<string>(); }
        set { Storage.Set(value); }
    }
}
```

MyModule/Drivers/MyCustomFieldDriver.cs:

```
public class MyCustomFieldDriver : ContentFieldDriver<MyCustomField> {

    // EditorTemplates/Fields/MyCustom.cshtml
    private const string TemplateName = "Fields/MyCustom";

    private static string GetPrefix(ContentField field, ContentPart part) {
        // handles spaces in field names
        return (part.PartDefinition.Name + "." + field.Name)
               .Replace(" ", "_");
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(ContentPart part, MyCustomField field, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Fields_MyCustom",
            field.Name,
            f => f.Name(field.Name)
                .SelectedValue(field.SelectedValue));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, MyCustomField field, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Fields_MyCustom_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
            TemplateName: TemplateName,
            Model: field,
            Prefix: GetPrefix(field, part)));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, MyCustomField field, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(field, GetPrefix(field, part), null, null);
        return Editor(part, field, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

MyModule/Views/Fields/MyCustom.cshtml:

```
@{ 
    var selectedValue = Model.SelectedValue;
}

<h1>@selectedValue</h1>
MyModule/Views/EditorTemplates/Fields/MyCustom.cshtml:

@model MyModule.Fields.MyCustomField

<select id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedValue)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.SelectedValue)"></select>

@using (Script.Foot()) {
    Script.Require("jQuery");

    <script>

        $(function () {
            // your own url ofcourse
            var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
                dd = $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedValue)");

            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    dd.append("<option value='" + this.name + "'>" + this.name + "</option>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

MyModule/Placement.info:

```
<Placement>
  <Place Fields_MyCustom_Edit="Content:3" />
  <Place Fields_MyCustom="Content:3" />
</Placement>
```

Answer (score 1):

In OrchardCMS we can create Custom Fields. Every field should be handled by admin so as to make it generic and for that purpose orchard has made things so much easy by providing us settings option.
So we can say that in orchardCMS when we create any custom field we have a setting part as well. All we are supposed to do is to create a setting folder and in that folder we need to create a setting class say DropDownFieldSetting.cs and here we need to write public properties required to be treated as settings by the admin.
Settings/DropDownFieldSettings.cs

```
   public class DropDownFieldSettings
    {
            public string Filter { get; set; }
    }
```

and another class under settings folder
settings/DropDownFieldEditorEvents.cs

```
public class DropDownFieldEditorEvents : ContentDefinitionEditorEventsBase 
    {
        public override IEnumerable<TemplateViewModel>
          PartFieldEditor(ContentPartFieldDefinition definition)
        {
            if (definition.FieldDefinition.Name == "DropDownCustomField")
            {
                var model = definition.Settings.GetModel<DropDownFieldSettings>();
                yield return DefinitionTemplate(model);
            }
        }

        public override IEnumerable<TemplateViewModel> PartFieldEditorUpdate(ContentPartFieldDefinitionBuilder builder, IUpdateModel updateModel)
        {

            var model = new DropDownFieldSettings();
            if (updateModel.TryUpdateModel(model, "DropDownFieldSettings", null, null))
            {
                builder.WithSetting("DropDownFieldSettings.Filter", model.Filter);               
                yield return DefinitionTemplate(model);
            }

        }
    }
```

When administrator enter some value in filter Field the following PartFieldEditorUpdate function gets invoked. here in this function this line saves your settings

```
builder.WithSetting("DropDownFieldSettings.Filter",model.Filter);
```

For complete idea about all this we can take a look at Orchard.Fields Module under Module folder in the root of OrcharCMS.